# Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I got this problem while installing Composer into UniserverZ, I run this command

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
```

and it returns the error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './extensions\php_curl.dll' - Attempt to access invalid address.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './extensions\php_openssl.dll' - Attempt to access invalid address.
>    in Unknown on line 0

Could some one help me. I already try to enable `php_curl.dll` and `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`. And also enable load module `mod_ssl` in `httpd.conf` . But it still not working and error still the same. I am trying to install Laravel5.

Comment: Did you already install the packages with your package manager (apt-get, zypper, etc.)?

Comment: @rinukkusu: `php_curl.dll` <-- OP is running windows

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem True, my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Uniform Server XII / Windows 7 64-bit / php 5.6

In the steps below *php* should be replaced with your php root directory, which for me was: B:\UniServerZ\core\php56
And *ext* is the name of your extensions directory, usually just "ext" or "extensions"

This worked for me:

1. Make sure your php path is in your PATH Environmental Variable:

   - Open Control Panel -> System -> Advances system settings -> Environmental Variables
   - You may have a Path variable in both your User variables and  your System variables, check both. If your php directory isn't listed, add it. If more than one php directory is listed, remove the extra ones.
2. Make sure you have these dll-s present:

   - *php*\libeay32.dll
   - *php*\libssh2.dll
   - *php*\ssleay32.dll
   - *php**ext*\php_curl.dll (where *ext* is your extension directory)
3. Edit your php.ini file in your php path, i.e. *php*\php.ini and make sure to have (or uncomment):

   - extension=*php**ext*\php_curl.dll (or just extension=php_curl.dll might work)
   - extension=php_openssl.dll
   - I also had, but not sure if it's relevant: curl.cainfo = *php*\extras\ssl\cacert.pem (your certificate)
   - and: openssl.cafile="B:\UniServerZ\core\php56\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
4. I also had to copy ALL FOUR of the above dll-s to my C:\Windows\System32 and my C:\Windows\SysWOW64 directories
5. And I had to reboot the machine (really, restarting the command prompt was not enough)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , I will test it now